# php regex finding exact number ranges

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to check for a number in a string within an exact range using purely regex?
What I mean is that I want to check if a string contains a number that ranges, for example, from 1 to 31 in VALUE, not length.

Comment: Why not extracting the number, converting it to integer so you can compare it with 1 and 31 ?

Comment: Frosty is right, you should it extract first and validate it as a number, and not as a string. However, the question lacks of some information. For example when you say "number in a string", is the number the only one in this string, or may it a string like `hello 42 world 15`?

Comment: @Frosty - not an answer to my question. @KingCrunch - I will only check for a specific place in the string and not look through all of it so it doesn't matter.

Comment: There are some third-party tools out there that expect a regexp to validate data. I guess this is probably the case.

Comment: *Please*... do not abuse regexes for things like that.

Comment: I simply do not wish to use multiple checks on one string if I can do away with only one. I don't see what's your problem here.

Comment: @jurchiks: it was just as suggestion, that's why I posted it as comment and not as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers of the range from 1 to 31 can be split into two groups: *one digit numbers* (1–9) and *two digit numbers* (10–31). And the latter can further be split into *whole decades* (10–29) and *partial decades* (30–31). These can be expressed as follows:

```
[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]
```

And to match only whole numbers and not just parts of them, you could use look-around assertions:

```
(?<!\d)([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?!\d)
```

Here `(?<!…)` means not preceded by `…` and `(?!…)` not followed by `…`.

Comment: Got the idea, thanks. But what are those (?<!\d) and (?!\d) for? Shouldn't just \s be enough?

Comment: @jurchiks: They are used to only match whole numbers and not only parts of numbers like `12` would also match the `12` in `12345` but `(?<!\d)12(?!\d)` wouldn’t.

Comment: @jurchiks: No, `\s` wouldn’t suffice. It wouldn’t match numbers at the begin or the end of a string as well as where not surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: Ahh, then I don't need it, I'm checking a string separated by spaces. If there is no space, validation fails and it means the input was invalid anyway, so...

Comment: @jurchiks: Do you have some examples?

Comment: The regex: "/\A(?<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]{8})[[:space:]](?<sum>[5-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9]|3[0-9][0-9]|400)[[:space:]](?<days>1[4-9]|2[0-9]|30)\z/", an example string: "omg23wtf 123 14". The string is stripped of multiple spaces and \t\r\n symbols. Works just fine here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php . There can't be much of anything there though because it's a text received via SMS.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously possible since you can always do this:

```
/^(1)|(2)|.....|(30)|(31)$/
```

And I bet the expression can be simplified for exact cases, However, IMHO it's just a way to make code unnecessarily complex to maintain.

I bet you'll enjoy this article: [How do I write a regular expression that matches an IPv4 dotted address?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/22/603788.aspx)

Comment: I never said that I absolutely MUST use regex for this, I was just interested in how to do it and it appears it's fairly simple. About the article - as a matter of fact I do :D

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, hope it can helps! ;)

```
/^([1-2]\d|3[01]|[1-9]){1}$/
```

or also without the "exactly 1", be sure, the round parentheses must be present:

```
/^([1-2]\d|3[01]|[1-9])$/
```